# mintty problems with Windows 8.1 on-screen keyboard (tablet) and Alt-Gr keys

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, cygwin, mintty

On a tablet running Windows 8.1 I installed Cygwin 2.0.0 64.

Unfortunately I have issues using the on-screen (virtual) keyboard with <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd> keys from within mintty.

Example: In Germany to get to the <kbd>@</kbd> character you have to press <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

This, however, doesn't work in mintty using the on-screen keyboard. Instead of <kbd>@</kbd> it produces the sequence *ESC CTL-Q*.

When I start bash from a Windows CMD terminal the <kbd>@</kbd> works nicely.
It also works when I use a real keyboad connected through USB.

The problem only exists when using a mintty window and the on-screen keyboard.

Does anybody have any advice?

Comment: Have you reported the problems to the mintty community?

Comment: No, actually I wasn't aware that mintty has it's own community...

Comment: From https://www.cygwin.com/lists.html "[cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/) In general, you should send questions and bug reports here". Most of the cygwin developers/maintainers hang out on this mailing list.

Comment: Somebody wrote mintty.  My suggestion is to report the behavior to whom ever is responsible for updating mintty since the its pretty clear the problem is a conflict between the on-screen keyboard and minty.  So the problem is either Cygwin or Mintty not clear based on your description which one it would be.

Comment: Thanks for the advice to use the cygwin mailing list. Actually, I read the cygwin documentation carefully and in "How To Ask Questions The Smart Way" Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange was mentioned to be a good starting point... I'm going to send my problem description to the cygwin mailing list now.